# java static block does not run in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I am using a `static` block to load `properties file` in my java app called `App1`

```
public class Configuration{ 
static {
    System.out.println("static ");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("./TwitterLog4j.properties"); 
    log = Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName());
    configProp = new Properties();

    try {

        configProp.load(Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("TwitterConfig.properties"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("TC100: Unable to load the connector configuration file. Configuration file is missing or is invalid.");
    } 

    CONSUMER_KEY = configProp.getProperty("APPKEY");
    CONSUMER_SECRET = configProp.getProperty("APPSECRET");

    }
}
```

After creating a `jar` of `App1`, I use it in `App2` where I use threading `(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))` to run `App1` by calling method of class `ConnWrapper` (see flow below). But my static block seems to run only once, does the JVM keeps the classes loaded even when my `App1` finishes?

Class Flow of `App1`

```
ConnWrapper Class --> Conn Class --> ConnInterface Class --> Configuration Class 
*( -->  = calls method of)
```

Comment: Static blocks are guaranteed to run only once when the class is loaded by the JVM. Your question and expectation is not clear, what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

A static block is loaded once per Classloader per jvm. Your variable 'configProp' is a static variable of the class you can use to access the properties, so why would you need to load it multiple times ?

```
public class Configuration{ 

public static Properties configProp;

static{
    reloadProperties();
}

public static void reloadProperties()
 {
    System.out.println("static ");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("./TwitterLog4j.properties"); 
    log = Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName());
    configProp = new Properties();

    try {

        configProp.load(Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("TwitterConfig.properties"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("TC100: Unable to load the connector configuration file. Configuration file is missing or is invalid.");
    } 

    CONSUMER_KEY = configProp.getProperty("APPKEY");
    CONSUMER_SECRET = configProp.getProperty("APPSECRET");

    }
}
```

Comment: hi @ramp, I need to change the properties file during runtime. After i wrote the code, I saw that the properties file changed but the results didn't showed it. I will remove the static block and variables, and use the constructor instead.

Comment: No, app properties are generally static data. You have to just reload it if the property file changes. See the edit on my post,

Answer (score 0):

This is static block as per java norms its loaded only once so how many times
we calling that method give us same result so threading concept is not necessary here